# Securing a web page and required resources with Google Cloud Storage and signed urls?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to secure access to premium content on my app engine web application. The content is an [Articulate](http://articulate.com/) module, it is a player.html with dozens of associated javascript, audio, and video resources. I am trying to use Google Cloud Storage to host the content.

My idea is that when a user who is authenticated with my app and has appropriate access requests the premium content, my app could sign a url to the player.html. What I am not sure about is how to handle all the associated resource files? Signed urls are simple enough for securing single files, but what about groups of files? Do I have to sign urls for all the content or is it possible to have a single signed url allow access to related files?

ACLs are not an option, because I rolled my own authentication rather than using oAuth and Google accounts.

Any thoughts or alternate strategies would be appreciated.

### Update 8.7.13

After reflecting and researching some more, I am wondering about configuring the GCS bucket as a website as per the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration).

If I understand the docs correctly, I would create a CNAME to point requests from my custom domain content.example.com to c.storage.googleapis.com, and request that arrive via this CNAME are served up as if they were a static webpage. Does anybody know what access controls are available (if any) to files served in this manner? Would files served this way also require signing / ACLs if they are not public?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your options here are somewhat limited. Below are two ideas, but both of them have fairly significant drawbacks. Neither's super great, unfortunately.

### Obfuscation

Make all associated resources publicly accessible and kept under an unguessable subdirectory. The user would use a signed URL to load the secured root resource, which would include links to the publicly accessible secondary resources. Downside: the sub-resources are not secured and could be downloaded by any party that knows the URL. Possible mitigation: periodically rotate sub-resource directory.

### Appengine Redirects

Change includes to route all resources through your appengine app, which would authenticate using its own scheme and redirect to a new signed URL for each subresource. Downside: lots of extra hops through appengine. So for example, player.html would include a movie as "https://yourapp.appspot.com/resources/movie.mov", which would hit your appengine app, which would in turn authenticate then redirect to the signed "https://storage.googleapis.com/yourbucket/movie.mov?signaturestuff"